# Error loading pipeline assembly

Tags: c#, xna

I recently changed programming PC, but when I tried to open my solution, it gave me this error:

> Error loading pipeline assembly "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Hogwart\HogwartLibrary\bin\x86\Debug\HogwartLibrary.dll"

Why? I read that it is a problem of references, but I don't find how to fix it...
I am using two libraries: the main one, "Hogwart" and the xml classes one "HogwartLibrary".

What is a pipeline assembly? And how to fix it?

Comment: Well, this was easier than I exepted, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline assembly is used build time and it contains content processors and importers which are used to "convert"/build raw files (xml, txt, etc) into xnb.
Basically it is used to make custom content files.

The error means that the DLL is not found. Simply just build the library in the solution.